# Training loss not decreasing when training - tensorflow gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, loss-function

I am training a graph neural network on a node cluster with one gpu Titan RTX. I am using Tensorflow-gpu 1.15 and it can recognize the gpu successfully. The training involves some tensors operations of type float 64, where the training set is formed by 256K sparse block-circulant matrices of moderate size. I evaluate 256 samples per run and the batch size is set to 32.

When I look at the loss graph in tb, I notice that even after evaluating more than 100K samples (after 24 hours of training) my training loss is not decaying at all: it looks noisy and quite flat. This is the plot from tb:

[image: training loss not decaying]

The loss is measured as the frobenious norm of an error matrix and it is supposed to decay. I am also using the adam optimizer with learning rate of 10^-3.
Any insights on why it is behaving like this? It is basically not learning anything.

I did a quick profiling to see which operations are the slowest, but cannot find something significant.

Could it be the GPU that I am using and the loss in performance due to the heavy memory allocation of float64? When I am checking the gpu usage, I allocate 60% of the memory (and I have the option to release it after operation).

Any suggestion or tips?

I have been using:
Tensorflow-gpu 1.15,
CUDA 10.0.130,
NCCL 2.4.7-CUDA-10.0.130,
cuDNN 7.6.3-CUDA-10.0.130.

Running on a remote server with 4 gpus Titan RTX (I am using 1 of them).

Comment: what kind of problem are you dealing with, then what kind of model you are using for training...? these parameters are important to tell also.

Comment: the NN should learn the matrix's weights from a set of sparse and symmetric matrices . The matrices are represented as a graph, therefore the model is a graph neural network. I am using Graph Net from deepmind and the model is EncodeProcessDecodeNonRecurrent

Comment: So you are using GraphNet, a TensorFlow library if I am not mistaken. How did you generate your graphs? What does your GraphNetwork look like?

Answer (score 0):

Type tf.float64 is not the problem when you select the correct optimizer when I am running on version 1 compatibility mode 'tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()'

1. Select the correct input data and target optimizer.
2. Select the correct tf.Variable.
3. Select the optimized equation or methods.
4. Input may require specific methods to transform to tf.float64 in compatibility mode 'tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()'
5. Running sessions have the same input and update of variables, arrays, or feed_dict.
6. Purpose of the optimizer when you need to find similarities or you need to find categories of their group.

Sample: Similarity scopes re-occurrence or all pixels compare small of change see it different.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import resize

import numpy as np

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
learning_rate = 0.1
global_step = 0
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

BATCH_SIZE = 1
IMG_SIZE = (32, 32)

history = [ ] 
history_Y = [ ]
list_file = [ ]
list_label = [ ]

for file in os.listdir("F:\\datasets\\downloads\\dark\\train") :
    image = plt.imread( "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\dark\\train\\" + file )
    image = resize(image, (32, 32))
    image = np.reshape( image, (1, 32, 32, 3) )
    list_file.append( image )
    list_label.append(1)

optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(
    learning_rate=0.1,
    beta1=0.9,
    beta2=0.999,
    epsilon=1e-08,
    use_locking=False,
    name='Adam'
)

var1 = tf.Variable(255.0, dtype=tf.dtypes.float64)
var2 = tf.Variable(10.0, dtype=tf.dtypes.float64)
X_var = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('X', dtype = tf.float64, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.dtypes.float64))
y_var = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('Y', dtype = tf.float64, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.dtypes.float64))
Z = tf.nn.l2_loss((var1 - X_var) ** 2 + (var2 - y_var) ** 2, name="loss")

cosine_loss = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(Z))
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

previous_train_loss = 0
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

    image = list_file[0]
    X = image
    Y = image

    for i in range(1000):
        global_step = global_step + 1
        train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={X_var:X, y_var:Y})
        history.append( train_loss )
        
        if global_step % 2 == 0 :
            var2 = var2 - 0.001
        if global_step % 4 == 0 and train_loss <=  previous_train_loss :
            var1 = var1 - var2 + 0.5
        print( 'steps: ' + str(i) )
        print( 'train_loss: ' + str(train_loss) )
        
        previous_train_loss = train_loss
        
sess.close()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Graph
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = history[:-1]

plt.plot(np.asarray(history))
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Without Cosine Similarity: All Pixels are comparing a bit of change they find the meaning.
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOuSb.png)

With Cosine Similarity: Re-occurrence of series supposed to consider same threads.
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khPe8.png)

Comment: May I ask what are the advantages of disable_eager_execution()? currently in my code tf is running on eager execution mode

Comment: My examples present a comparison of the enable and disable eager execution when your environment is working in different modes. Some programs work in eager but not none eager mode I answered your question by cosine similarity can create no loss value graph falling but similar output in range.